# Start menu items and desktop items lost after adding Windws domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain

I added a Windows domain on Windows 7 Prof and later deleted it again (local again). Now many of my menu items in the start menu are gone. Also the desktop items of those programs are gone. Is there an easy way to get them all back at once?

Comment: Did you check c:/users/ for different accounts?  (E.g. a c:/users/Zardoz@my_computer_name and a C:/users/zardoz_at_my_domain ) (First name created likely has just the name)

Comment: DId you always login to a local account when you joined the domain, or did you use a domain account during that time?  Which account are you using now?

Comment: @francisswest -- I never used the the domain account. I only used the local account. I switched back from domain to local, and now only have the local account that I had before the domain trial thing.

Comment: @Hennes -- there is only one account left, my local account (beside the "public" one).

Answer (score 1):

This is what it sounds like to me:

- You had a local user account
- You created a domain and joined a domain
- You logged in on the domain account and modified the users settings
- Left the domain
- Used you local account again

The two accounts are different.  One is local only to the computer - think of it as a domain of one computer.  The other is stored locally, but part of the domain.

In order to get the changes you made from the domain account to your local account you need to go to the `c:\users` folder.  You should see two accounts, one named for the domain.  Copy the contents of that folder into your local account and you should be good to go.  You should turn on `show hidden files and folders` in the Explorer menu to get all the files.

Comment: Sorry for being unambiguous, but I never used the domain account (never logged in). I just deleted it again (by saying that I am not part of a corporation network). Then I logged in again with my local account and most programs in the start menu are gone. Even when I create a new admin user those a not there. But the programs still exist and can be executed.